# Proving $d(x,y) = \left| \frac{x}{1 + |x|} - \frac{y}{1 + |y|} \right|$ is a metric in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

As the title says, I'm having problems proving some metric conditions. Obviously, $d$ is symmetric and always non negative (by absolute value properties), but when I set $d(x,y) = 0$ I get stuck with $y|x| + y = x |y| + x $, and can't continue further on.

Any hints on this property (and even with the triangle inequality) would be appreciated.

Comment: To show $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$, consider breaking it into cases based on whether x and y are negative or not.

Comment: Thanks! The cases worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$d(x,y) = 0 \implies \frac{x}{1+|x|} = \frac {y}{1+|y|} \implies \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} = \frac{|y|}{1+|y|} \implies |x| = |y|$$

So $$d(x,y) = 0 \implies \frac{x}{1+|x|} = \frac{y}{1+|x|} \implies x = y$$